# I have a script that is working fine on mozilla, but not working at all on ie 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have a script, which gives me an error when loading it with ie. The error is 
"Message: 'parent().data(...)' is null or not an object"

This is a link that i click:

```
<a onclick="selectPage($(this));" href="#">Menu</a>
```

and it does nothing in ie. in mozilla, it shows the correct page just fine.

This is the selectPage function:

```
function selectPage(liobj){
//alert(liobj.parent().data("page_data").type);

$(".canvas_page").each(function(index, object){
    $(object).hide();
});

if(liobj == "main"){
    $("div#site_options").show();
    $("#pagesList").children().removeClass("selected");
    $("#sidebar .button").addClass("selected");
    return;
}

liobj.parent().data("canvas_page").show();
liobj.parent().siblings().removeClass("selected");
liobj.parent().addClass("selected");
$("#sidebar .button").removeClass("selected");
```

}

I can't seem to understand why the page is not shown in ie, but in mozilla is shown just fine.

Thank you for any advices you may have for me.

Comment: Try testing on other browsers as well and using a tool like JSLint/JSHint. Nomtimes its something stupid like a missing comma...

Comment: As i said, in mozilla it works fine. I tried JSLint, but that didn't do any good. The link is inside a "<li>" tag.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
<a onclick="selectPage(this);" href="#">Menu</a>
```

The function changed like this:

```
 function selectPage(obj){
  var liobj = $(obj);
//alert(liobj.parent().data("page_data").type);

$(".canvas_page").each(function(index, object){
    $(object).hide();
});

if(liobj == "main"){
    $("div#site_options").show();
    $("#pagesList").children().removeClass("selected");
    $("#sidebar .button").addClass("selected");
    return;
}

liobj.parent().data("canvas_page").show();
liobj.parent().siblings().removeClass("selected");
liobj.parent().addClass("selected");
$("#sidebar .button").removeClass("selected");
}
```

Comment: -1; how on earth is this ever going to change anything? All you've done is changed where `jQuery(elem)` is called so that it's called in the function. This cannot ever change anything unless `selectPage` is in a closure which defines `$` locally.